# Does 그리운 걸 means as always or I miss?

Tags: translation

I have an argument with a friend about this sentence 그리운 걸 엘런 i say it means i miss you eren and she said it mean as always eren... can anyone help?

Comment: maybe, 걸 is a girl ?

Comment: what is the context of this sentence? What would you say is your level of Korean?

Answer (score 1):

그립다 is a descriptive verb meaning that [something is missed or longed for](http://dic.naver.com/search.nhn?dicQuery=%EA%B7%B8%EB%A6%BD%EB%8B%A4).

> 가족이 그립다 - I miss my family.

Note that because it's a descriptive verb, the thing *that is missed* takes the subject particle 이/가.

Using the adnominal - ㄴ 걸 ending is an idiomatic way to end phrases that have a regretful sentiment.

If you were to use the name 엘런, the natural way to say it would be

> (나는) 엘런이 그리운 걸

"To me, Eren is a missed thing" or more naturally, just "I miss (you) Eren ".

Answer (score 0):

**그리운**

나는 9월이 되면 고향이 그립다. I miss a native town at every September

나는 늘 그가 그립다. I always miss him.

나는 겨울에는 고향이 더 그립다. I miss a native town more at winter.

그리운 고향 missing native town : In my thought, we can translate as follows : I always miss a native town.

**걸**

> 약간의 반박 또는 감탄 small disagree or exclamation

A : 아름다운 걸 beautiful ! : When B think that it is beautiful or
it has a little fault.

> 후회 regret in conversation or 독백 monologue

자둘 걸 Because I did not sleep, now I regret.

@ 걸=것을 :

내일 여행갈 걸(것을) 준비해 두었다. I prepared for a
tomorrow's tour.

그가 멋진 걸 어떡해 I like him because he is fascinating.